# on select event rewrite data list

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have two "from" and "to" drop down number list fields. I just want when "from" number selected rewrite "to" number list data where number more then "from" value number. And the same backware when "to" number selected rewrite "from" number list where number less then selected "to" value.

I'm creating three events:

1) On from item selected event working only first time, the rest of the time working not correct

2) On to item selected event the same workink only fist time, the rest of the time working not correct

3) On from item clear event for the reset all data list but working not correct: resetting only "to" data list, "from" data list just clearing.

html code:

```
<select id="formadditional-age_from" class="form-control" 
name="FormAdditional[age_from]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<select id="formadditional-age_to" class="form-control" name="FormAdditional[age_to]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

jquery code:

```
const select2Conf = {
            allowClear: true,
            minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
            width: 200
        },
        age_to_item = $('#formadditional-age_to'),
        age_from_item = $('#formadditional-age_from'),
        age_option_list = $('option', age_from_item).clone();

age_from_item.select2({
  ...select2Conf,
  placeholder: 'From',
});

age_to_item.select2({
  ...select2Conf,
  placeholder: 'To',
});

age_from_item.on('select2:select', function(e){
        let data = e.params.data,
            val = age_to_item.val();

        age_to_item
            .html(age_option_list.filter(o => age_option_list[o].value === '' || parseInt(age_option_list[o].value)>=parseInt(data.id)))
            .val(val).trigger('change');

    });

age_to_item.on('select2:select', function(e){
  let data = e.params.data,
      val = age_from_item.val();

  age_from_item
    .html(age_option_list.filter(o => age_option_list[o].value === '' || parseInt(age_option_list[o].value)<=parseInt(data.id)))
    .val(val).trigger('change');
});

age_from_item.on('select2:clearing', function(e){
        $(this)
            .html(age_option_list)
            .val("").trigger('change');

            age_to_item
            .html(age_option_list)
            .val("").trigger('change');
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bemulima/18mkrbe2/21/

Why my code working uncorrectly?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/q7He9/2 for a cleaner solution which is enough for what you try to achieve.

Comment: thank you @Haris for your comment, your code is realy good solution.

Comment: No problem, just pasted it as answer for easier access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <select class="form-control" name="from">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="1000">1000 cc</option>
        <option value="1200">1200 cc</option>
        <option value="1400">1400 cc</option>
        <option value="1600">1600 cc</option>
        <option value="1800">1800 cc</option>
        <option value="2000">2000 cc</option>
        <option value="2500">2500 cc</option>
        <option value="3000">3000 cc</option>
        <option value="3500">3500 cc</option>
        <option value="4000">4000 cc</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" name="to">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="1000">1000 cc</option>
        <option value="1200">1200 cc</option>
        <option value="1400">1400 cc</option>
        <option value="1600">1600 cc</option>
        <option value="1800">1800 cc</option>
        <option value="2000">2000 cc</option>
        <option value="2500">2500 cc</option>
        <option value="3000">3000 cc</option>
        <option value="3500">3500 cc</option>
        <option value="4000">4000 cc</option>
    </select>
```

// Jquery //

```
$('select[name=from]').on('change', function(){
    var self = this;
    $('select[name=to]').find('option').prop('disabled', function(){
        return this.value && this.value < self.value && self.value
    });
});

$('select[name=to]').on('change', function(){
    var self = this;
    $('select[name=from]').find('option').prop('disabled', function(){
        return this.value && this.value > self.value && self.value
    });
});
```